# WIFI driver not found in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers

I am running ubuntu RedmiBook-14-APCS with windows 10.But now I cannot connect with wifi."No wifi adapter is found" issue has been created.I have tried so many solution but didn't work any.

while running: sudo lshw -C network
*-network
description: Network controller

```
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 32
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
   resources: irq:60 memory:c0200000-c03fffff
```

*-network

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@3:2
   logical name: usb0
   serial: c2:89:a6:02:52:52
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.120 link=yes multicast=yes
```

while running:dmesg | grep ath10k:

```
[    2.046847] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.312518] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: loading /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -22
[    2.312576] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Failed to find firmware-N.bin (N between 2 and 6) from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0: -2
[    2.312582] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[    2.312586] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
[    2.644268] Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio 

snd_hda_codec_hdmi edac_mce_amd kvm_amd joydev snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg amdgpu snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel ath10k_pci aesni_intel snd_pcm crypto_simd iommu_v2 cryptd gpu_sched glue_helper snd_seq_midi ath10k_core ttm rapl snd_seq_midi_event ath snd_rawmidi input_leds drm_kms_helper serio_raw sparse_keymap cec hid_multitouch efi_pstore mac80211 snd_seq rc_core btusb btrtl snd_seq_device btbcm i2c_algo_bit snd_timer btintel fb_sys_fops bluetooth syscopyarea cfg80211 wmi_bmof snd_rn_pci_acp3x snd sysfillrect ecdh_generic ecc k10temp libarc4 snd_pci_acp3x sysimgblt ccp soundcore mac_hid rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet acpi_tad mii sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic nvme i2c_piix4 nvme_core xhci_pci crc32_pclmul xhci_pci_renesas video wmi i2c_hid hid
```

Answer (score 1):

You clearly have the correct driver:

> driver=ath10k_pci

What you do not have is the required firmware:

> loading /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin failed with
> error -22

Let’s see if an update will get the required firmware. With a working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y upgrade
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

If the firmware is still missing, do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.190_all.deb
sudo dpkg i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot. You should be all set.

**EDIT**: I notice that the board-2.bin file has just recently been updated: https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin

Let’s back up your current file and download the newest:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
sudo mv board-2.bin  board-2.bak
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin    
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
sudo dmesg | grep ath
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: I tried all of these commands.but nothing happedn.wifi adapter not found.

Comment: When I ran : sudo dpkg -i linuxfirmware*.deb (Reading database ... 202439 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-firmware_1.190_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.190) over (1.190) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.190) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-53-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p5
I: (UUID=5ecc47f1-9b99-4fad-aa26-d4fd42181eff)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

Comment: Let's see: `ls -al /usr/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0` Thanks.

Comment: ls -al /usr/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0                                                                       total 1996
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 মে       29 13:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 মে       29 01:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 584036 আগস্ট     20  2020 board-2.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8124 আগস্ট     20  2020 board.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 733784 আগস্ট     20  2020 firmware-4.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 700988 আগস্ট     20  2020 firmware-6.bin

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: When I ran : dmesg | grep ath10k .It shows:[    2.046290] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.320441] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0847
[    2.385722] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to fetch board data for bus=pci,vendor=168c,device=003e,subsystem-vendor=11ad,subsystem-device=0847 from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: now sudo dmesg | grep ath:: [    1.760124] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.028687] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0847
[    2.028689] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    2.029208] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 29eb8ca1
[    2.093453] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 ed5f849a

Comment: Looks fine. Is the wireless now working?